# How do I disable NVDA's arrow key navigation

Tags: javascript, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I have a collection of buttons inside a div, with some javascript to move focus between them in response to arrow key events.

When I test this with NVDA/Firefox/Windows it seems that NVDA overrides my arrow key handler and moves focus according to its own rules. This is a problem because my widget is highly customisable, dynamic, and responsive - so the rules for moving focus around are quite complex.

Neither Voiceover nor ChromeVox has this behaviour.

I noticed that adding role="gridcell" to each button seems to fix this, but I'd prefer not to do that because it means screenreaders won't treat my buttons as buttons. I also really don't want to change the html structure (e.g. wrapping each button in another element) unless it's absolutely necessary.

Is there a way (e.g. aria or proprietary attribute) to tell NVDA not to apply its own arrow key behaviour to the buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all your buttons are in a container (span or div), you can add role=application to the container and that will force **all** keyboard events to go to your application instead of to assistive technology.  Role=application should be used very sparingly, though.

```
<div role=application>
   <button>alpha</button><br>
   <button>beta</button><br>
   <button>gamma</button><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing something very similar by adding role="toolbar" to the container; it fixed my issue with unwanted NVDA arrow key interception. Semantically it's totally correct as my widget is "a container for grouping a set of controls, such as buttons, menubuttons, or checkboxes" so I'm pretty happy with that.

Answer (score 8):

Consider that by overriding a user's expected behavior, you run the risk of creating a completely unusable, or even inaccessible, interface.

I **strongly** recommend against trying to do this.

Regardless, any ARIA you add to try to override it can affect non-NVDA users. NVDA intercepts arrow keys, so JavaScript cannot act until NVDA has already reacted to the arrow keys.

Note that NVDA users can already navigate between buttons using `b` and `Shift` + `b`, so they do not need to rely on `Tab`.

Now, all that being said, you may find an existing pattern that is similar to what you are trying to achieve in the [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices](http://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/).

If you can outline your *objective* and maybe show an example, it is possible I can identify some existing patterns or techniques that will allow you to achieve your goal without risking a broken experience.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually authored the widget originally according to the "toolbar" section from the ARIA authoring practices page you linked - http://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/#toolbar. But I realised I didn't apply role=toolbar to the container: adding that role seems to change NVDA’s behaviour to be more reasonable.

The widget is basically a “grid of buttons” that allows symbols to be entered into an input area.

Comment: Ah, yes, I have forgotten a `role` more than once.